# Jquery targeting conundrum

Tags: jquery

I had a nicely striped table with some nifty mouseover effects that was working fine until I looked at it today.  I didn't change anything related to this functionality recently but it's no longer working.  The jquery code looks like this:

```
$(".striped tr").mouseover(function(){$(this).addClass("over");}).mouseout(function(){$(this).removeClass("over");});
$(".striped tr:even").addClass("alt");
```

The first selector works and I get the mouseover function.  The second one apparently fails on the same table.  I tried replacing the .striped target with the ID of the table and then it works, but this function needs to be applied to multiple table IDs.

Anyone ideas folks?

Comment: You might want to add the HTML you are referring to. As a sidenote: you can use toggleClass instead of the addClass/removeClass methods.

Comment: Are you using jQuery hosted by Google or did you download it and host it yourself?

Comment: Hosted jquery.  Submitter Terry got the target working by adding tbody to the target.  I'm waiting to click answered (have a 10 minute delay).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `tbody` to your selector

```
$(".striped tbody tr")
```

Comment: @Josh, strange, it shouldn't make any difference. Did you perchance use `.striped > tr` instead of `.striped tr`?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Adding `tbody` makes the `:even` selector work within the `tbody`.  Otherwise it tries to select based on the zero-index of all rows in the table including the `thead`.

Comment: @Terry, ah, indeed it makes sense with the `:even` selector. Thank you for your clarification :)

Comment: I'm not sure why it makes a difference either - it was working the last time I looked at the page...